# Complex nonlinear equation solution

Tags: nonlinear

I am trying to find an analytic/numeric solution for a set of equations involving functions, summation, and complex quantities.

Definitions:

```
step = 1;
num = 15;
rho = Range[step , num, step];
theta = Most[Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10]];
area[l_] := \[Pi] (2 step l - step^2) 1/Length[theta]
```

(I choose functions below arbitarily)

```
K11[a_, b_] := I a + a b + a Cos[b]
K12[a_, b_] := Conjugate[K11[a, b]]
K21[a_, b_] := (I a + a Sin[b])^2 + a Cos[(2 b)/3]
K22[a_, b_] := Conjugate[K21[a, b]]
C1[a_, b_] := K11[a, b] - K12[a, b]
```

Equations:

```
eq1 = -a1 + I Sum[  Conjugate[ (r1[\[Rho], \[Theta]] K11[\[Rho], \[Theta]] + r2[\[Rho], \[Theta]] K12[\[Rho], \[Theta]])] area[\[Rho]], {\[Rho], rho}, {\[Theta], theta}];
eq2 = -a2 +  I Sum[  Conjugate[ (r1[\[Rho], \[Theta]] K21[\[Rho], \[Theta]] + r2[\[Rho], \[Theta]] K22[\[Rho], \[Theta]])] area[\[Rho]], {\[Rho], rho}, {\[Theta], theta}];
eq3 = -4 Im[r1[\[Rho], \[Theta]] (K11[\[Rho], \[Theta]] a1 + K21[\[Rho], \[Theta]] a2)] -  C1[\[Rho], \[Theta]] (n1[\[Rho], \[Theta]] + 1) + C2 (1 - n1[\[Rho], \[Theta]]) (*C2 is a parameter*);
eq4 = -4 Im[ r2[\[Rho], \[Theta]] (K12[\[Rho], \[Theta]] a1 + K22[\[Rho], \[Theta]] a2)] - C1[\[Rho], \[Theta]] (n2[\[Rho], \[Theta]] + 1) + 0 (1 - n2[\[Rho], \[Theta]]) ;
eq5 = -1 r1[\[Rho], \[Theta]] + I n1[\[Rho], \[Theta]] Conjugate [(K11[\[Rho], \[Theta]] a1 +  K21[\[Rho], \[Theta]] a2)] ;
eq6 = -1 r2[\[Rho], \[Theta]] + I n2[\[Rho], \[Theta]] Conjugate [(K12[\[Rho], \[Theta]] a1 + K22[\[Rho], \[Theta]] a2)] ;
```

Condition and variables:

```
eqn={eq1==0,eq2==0,eq3==0,eq4==0,eq5==0,eq6==0}

Var= {a1,a2,r1,r2,n1,n2}
```

Problem:

Here, I want to plot a graph between (a1^2 vs C2). For that, I need to get analytic or numeric solution of the variables most of which are the functions of position and angle as given above. I couldn't deal using elimination method and solve feature.

Any help is appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Do you have a function for area? That seems unspecified.

Comment: @Kevin Ausman Hi Kevin, Sorry I missed it. I have updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand. You want to solve for six variables, but r1,r2,n1,n2 are written in your code as functions. If I remove the `[\[Rho], \[Theta]]` that follows each of your r1,r2,n1,n2 in your code then `Simplify[Reduce[{eq1==0, eq2==0,eq3==0,eq4==0,eq5==0,eq6==0},var]]` seems to work for me. The result is still large and complicated with some Conjugate remaining, but perhaps giving it a little more information about your variables might let it get rid of some of that. Is anything in this helpful?

Comment: @bill Thanks bill, my first idea was to remove all rho and theta dependencies and reduce/solve it as you suggested. However, it didn't work(says cannot be solved with the method available). Summation in the first two equation increases complexity i guess.

Comment: I had all this working an hour ago and now it doesn't work anymore. Now I see you have trailing ==0 for eq3,4,5,6 but you then later do eqn={...eq3==0,eq4==0,eq5==0,eq6==0} so that gives you eq3==0==0 etc. That may just be a posting typo. I don't know if that is the real problem. But I don't see any reason that Reduce shouldn't be able to solve this

Comment: @Bill.definitely a typo, removed extra "==0" from the equations. still doesn't seem to work. If possible could you please attach your previous equations syntax after removing {rho, theta], the time it was working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I didn't save the working version I had, but perhaps this will help.

```
step=1;
num=15;
rho=Range[step , num, step];
theta=Most[Range[0,2 Pi,2 Pi/10]];
area[l_]:=Pi(2 step l-step^2)/Length[theta];
K11[a_,b_]:=I a+a b+a Cos[b];
K12[a_,b_]:=Conjugate[K11[a,b]];
K21[a_,b_]:=(I a+a Sin[b])^2+a Cos[2 b/3];
K22[a_,b_]:=Conjugate[K21[a,b]];
C1[a_,b_]:=K11[a, b]-K12[a,b];
eq1=Simplify[-a1+I Sum[Conjugate[r1 K11[ρ,θ]+r2 K12[ρ,θ]]area[ρ],{ρ,rho},{θ,theta}]];
eq2=Simplify[-a2+I Sum[Conjugate[r1 K21[ρ,θ]+r2 K22[ρ,θ]]area[ρ],{ρ,rho},{θ,theta}]];
eq3= -4 Im[r1(K11[ρ,θ]a1+K21[ρ,θ]a2)]-C1[ρ,θ](n1+1)+C2(1-n1);
eq4= -4 Im[r2(K12[ρ,θ]a1+K22[ρ,θ]a2)]-C1[ρ,θ](n2+1)+0 (1-n2);
eq5= -1 r1+I n1 Conjugate[K11[ρ,θ]a1+K21[ρ,θ]a2];
eq6= -1 r2+I n2 Conjugate[K12[ρ,θ]a1+K22[ρ,θ]a2];
Var= {a1,a2,r1,r2,n1,n2};
Reduce[eq1==0&&eq2==0,Var]
```

You can then use `Simplify` and `N` on the output from Reduce to make the result much smaller and possibly see what you are looking for in that. The `Simplify` on eq1 and eq2 make those dramatically simpler because of your summation over regular angles.

I'm not certain if your complete system will solve or not, I didn't wait for that because as you mentioned, you were just making up arbitrary equations for each Knn.

I'm not certain what it is in the way you wrote the code and was provoking `Reduce` to say that it could not solve the system. I did see that warning once, but I didn't save the code at that point to try to track down the reason for that.

I'm not certain whether your r1,r2 are real radius or not. If they are and you tell `Reduce` that `Element[r1|r2,Reals]` then the code speeds up dramatically. Anything that you assume, but you don't tell Mathematica, then it will assume the worst case with everything as unknown complex, possibly zero, possibly infinite, possibly etc. Are ρ and θ real? If so then telling Mathematica that might make your problem much easier to solve.

So I'm not sure where to go, if anywhere, with this now. I can't even seem to get it to solve eq3 for C2. Can you at least reproduce what I've shown here? Can you try to track down what the source of the "Reduce can't solve" warning?

Comment: Thanks Bill,  r1 and r2 are complex numbers in my case, However, n1 and n2 are reals. Also,ρ and θ are real.  Yeah, I can reproduce to the point you did for eq1 and eq2, but when solving for 6 equations with 6 variables, I can't get the solution. "Reduce can't solve" warning isn't there but its keeps running.

Comment: `Simplify[Reduce[eq1==0&&eq2==0&&eq3==0&&Element[n1|n2|ρ|θ,Reals],{a1,a2,r1,r2,n1,n2,C2}],Element[n1|n2|ρ|θ,Reals]]` Beyond that I don't know what to say.

Comment: @ Bill I will look for it. Thanks for your time and help Bill.